# How to record an audio sequence to a file in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, audio, sequencing

I've made a Node.js program for generating procedural animations from a simulation. I want to add sound effects to the animations, but I haven't been able to find any libraries for generating a sequence of audio from pre-recorded sound effects.

For example, I want to basically have something like the following.

```js
import sequencer from "some-library";

const LENGTH = 30; // seconds
const recording = sequencer.createRecording(LENGTH);

recording.playSound("mysound.mp3", 5.0); // play at 5s
recording.playSound("mysound.mp3", 7.5); // play at 7.5s
recording.playSound("other.mp3", 20.5);     // play at 20.5s

recording.saveToFile("output.mp3"); // save to file after sequencing
```

Are there any pre-existing npm libraries which can do this? Or any resources to point me in the right direction?

I've looked into several audio recording libraries on npm, but all of them are for recording from an audio source (e.g. microphone) and are not what I am looking for.

Comment: Leaving aside if this is on topic on SO,  This answer to a 2015  [audacity post](https://forum.audacityteam.org/t/audacity-with-cli/427200) provides a link to SOX which has a CLI. This is not a recommendation, and I've never used it nor am I about to, but it may be technically possible to run it as a child process and drive it from Node to do what you want. FWIW as a lead, and there are probably alternatives.

Comment: Thanks @traktor, I'll look into sox. It might be able to do what I'm looking for. There's also node bindings for sox which would help me out

Comment: There is also FFMPEG  - how could I have forgotten? It's ability to do simple things is only outweighed by the difficulty of determining what command line arguments to supply to it to get it ( ffmpeg) to do them ...

Comment: Yeah I'm already using ffmpeg to assemble the frames of the animation into a video file, so I might just try and figure out the flags to use that lol